# name field of static variable in elf file

Tags: c, gcc, static

I'm just curious about the name field for a static variable. I have this code

```
int main ()
{
 static uint8_t var_1[10] = {1};
 static uitn8_t var_2[10] = {0};
  
return 1;
}
```

if I use `readelf -a foo | grep var_2` I see the following:

```
38: 0000601058  10  OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT  26  var_2.2482
```

I was wondering what that .2482 means, is it some sort index for variables. I'm also using gcc. thanks

Comment: similar Q on [S.E.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471792/what-is-the-number-in-readelf-symbol-table-name)

Comment: ok, copied to answer area

Answer (score 1):

Compilers, linkers, object files, debuggers etc utilize a concept widely known as ["name mangling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to ensure that identifiers used in a program are unique and to distinguish between them internally - because a programming language may allow the same name for an identifier in several places. "Name mangling" isn't really standardized but each tool tend to use its own name mangling scheme.